How are \fontdimens for a font chosen?
I have noticed that some fonts in LaTeX seem a lot more "spaced out" (e.g. Latin Modern) compared to other fonts which feel more "cramped" (e.g. STIX2). This is most noticeable when comparing Palatino derivatives. For example, URW Palladio (using the mathpazo package) is more spaced out compared to TeX Gyre Pagella (using the tgpagella package). Here are the images in the linked pages:

(mathpazo)

(tgpagella)
After doing some research, it seems like this "spacey-ness" or "cramped-ness" of a font is determined by the various \fontdimen parameters, in particular \fontdimen2, \fontdimen3, and \fontdimen4. Sure enough, comparing the \fontdimens for the above two examples I get:
mathpazo:
fontdimen2: 2.91pt
fontdimen3: 1.75pt
fontdimen4: 0.7pt

tgpagella:
fontdimen2: 2.5pt
fontdimen3: 1.25pt
fontdimen4: 0.83pt

My understanding is that this means that spaces in mathpazo take values in the range [2.91 - 0.7, 2.91 + 1.75] = [2.21, 4.66] (with the "ideal" or "target" space being 2.91pt) while spaces in tgpagella take values in the range [2.5 - 0.83, 2.5 + 1.25] = [1.67, 3.75] (with the "ideal" or "target" space being 2.5pt). This does seem to explain why the two fonts look different in terms of their spacing.
Here's the source for the above:
\documentclass{article}

% Comment out exactly one line below:
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
% \usepackage{tgpagella}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

fontdimen2: \the\fontdimen2\font

fontdimen3: \the\fontdimen3\font

fontdimen4: \the\fontdimen4\font

\end{document}

My questions are:

Why such a difference for essentially the same font?
Who is deciding the \fontdimen values? Are they in the font files themselves? Is whoever is maintaining the CTAN package deciding these values? Is TeX/LaTeX somehow computing these values by looking at the fonts?
Are there any disadvantages to manually tweaking these values? For example, if I find that I want STIX2 to have a more spaced-out look because by default it looks too cramped, is it advisable for me to just modify the values? Or will this lead to problems (e.g. maybe the defaults were very carefully chosen, and so by modifying the \fontdimen values some documents will look very ugly)? Or maybe the "cramped" look is intentional because that's just the kind of font that STIX2 is, whereas Latin Modern is a such-and-such font so it ought to be spaced out more (but the Palatino-derivatives example above makes me skeptical that such a thing is going on).


note that stix is based (rather loosely) on Times Roman and Times was designed for narrow newspaper columns and is heavier and tighter than computer or latin modern by design....."Or maybe the "cramped" look is intentional because that's just the kind of font that STIX2 is"

@DavidCarlisle do you know why the xheight is variously 469, 459 and 449 for tgpagella?

@cfr no idea, you'd need to ask the tex gyre team

The source of the values varies1.
$ less $(kpsewhich qplr.afm)
StartFontMetrics 2.0
Comment Generated by FontForge 20170731
Comment Creation Date: Tue May 08 11:22:00 2018
FontName TeXGyrePagella-Regular
FullName TeXGyrePagella-Regular
FamilyName TeXGyrePagella
Weight Regular
Notice (Copyright 2006-2018 for TeX Gyre extensions by B. Jackowski, J.M. Nowacki, et al. (on behalf of TeX USERS GROUPS). Vietnamese characters were added by Han The Thanh.)
ItalicAngle 0
IsFixedPitch false
UnderlinePosition -100
UnderlineThickness 50
Version 2.501
EncodingScheme FontSpecific
FontBBox -851 -419 1512 1212
CapHeight 692
XHeight 469
Ascender 662
Descender -269
Comment PFM parameters: TeXGyrePagella-Regular 0 0 0xEE
Comment TFM designsize: 10 (in points)
Comment TFM fontdimen  1: 0          (slant)
Comment TFM fontdimen  2: 2.5        (space)
Comment TFM fontdimen  3: 1.25       (space stretch)
Comment TFM fontdimen  4: 0.83       (space shrink)
Comment TFM fontdimen  5: 4.49       (xheight)
Comment TFM fontdimen  6: 10         (quad)
Comment TFM fontdimen  7: 0.83       (extra space)
Comment TFM fontdimen  8: 6.92       (non-standard: uc height)
Comment TFM fontdimen  9: 7.26       (non-standard: ascender)
Comment TFM fontdimen 10: 10.98      (non-standard: accented cap height)
Comment TFM fontdimen 11: 2.81       (non-standard: descender depth)
Comment TFM fontdimen 12: 12.12      (non-standard: max height)
Comment TFM fontdimen 13: 4.19       (non-standard: max depth)
Comment TFM fontdimen 14: 5          (non-standard: digit width)
Comment TFM fontdimen 15: 0.96       (non-standard: uc stem)
Comment TFM fontdimen 16: 12         (non-standard: baselineskip)
Comment TFM fontdimen 17: 0.84       (non-standard: lc stem)
Comment TFM fontdimen 18: 0.55556    (non-standard: u, i.e., font unit)
Comment TFM fontdimen 19: 0.2        (non-standard: overshoot)
Comment TFM fontdimen 20: 0.34       (non-standard: thin stem, hair)
Comment TFM fontdimen 21: 0.44       (non-standard: cap thin stem, i.e., cap_hair)
Comment TFM fontdimen 22: 2.5        (math axis)
Comment TFM headerbyte  9: FontSpecific
Comment TFM headerbyte 49: TeX Gyre Pagella
Comment TFM headerbyte 72: 234

shows the various dimensions are recorded in the Adobe Font Metric files. This is common in AFMs for fonts designed for TeX, but rare otherwise. For example, we do not find this in the URW AFM used by mathpazo.
$ less $(kpsewhich uplr8a.afm)
StartFontMetrics 3.0
Comment Copyright (URW)++,Copyright 1999 by (URW)++ Design & Development
Comment Creation Date: 12/22/1999
Comment See the file COPYING (GNU General Public License) for license conditions.
FontName URWPalladioL-Roma
FullName URW Palladio L Roman
FamilyName URW Palladio L
Weight Roman
ItalicAngle 0.0
IsFixedPitch false
UnderlinePosition -100
UnderlineThickness 50
Version 1.05
Notice (URW)++,Copyright 1999 by (URW)++ Design & Development
EncodingScheme AdobeStandardEncoding
FontBBox -166 -283 1021 943
CapHeight 692
XHeight 469
Descender -281
Ascender 726
StartCharMetrics 316

However, this does not mean the values are arbitrary in these cases. Rather, the font dimensions would typically be calculated from dimensions which are specified in the AFM files. (Note that the TeX font dimensions are comments in the tgpagella AFM. They are not used by other applications, though other applications should produce similar spacing etc. modulo layout algorithms etc.)
This is typically done by one of various tools used to produce TFMs and other support files for (La)TeX font support packages such as fontinst, afm2tfm, fontforge or autoinst.
So the source of the values is almost always the font foundry or designer, though package authors may be responsible for some modifications. For example, gentium-tug modifies the placement of some accents in the TFMs, so the output for 8bit engines differs from the output for Unicode engines, which use the original metrics from the opentype fonts.
So ultimately, the font dimensions are determined by the person preparing the TFMs, but package authors normally allow them to be determined by the values specified in the fonts. That is, while I could decide on whatever values I wish for fonts I package, I do not normally do so2.
This is not to say I never do so, but that I do so only if that's required to correct obvious bugs. For example, the Adobe Font Metric files for some Latin Modern fonts are buggy. So, in that particular case, I use the foundry's TeX Font Metric files to correct the AFMs. If the TFMs were also buggy or (as would usually be the case) unavailable, I would have to come up with some non-arbitrary method to correct them, assuming it wasn't possible to get the metrics changed at source.
While there is nothing to prevent you altering font dimensions in documents, I would not recommend doing so. For one thing, you have to drop down to a lower level than the one on which LaTeX's font selection mechanism operates. This risks introducing all kinds of inconsistencies and bugs. If you really want to modify the dimensions in this way, produce a modified font package - probably based on virtual fonts - and use new names for the font families you create3.
If you do this, I suspect you may be less than pleased with the results. Font dimensions are typically chosen holistically. That is, the various dimensions are designed to work together to produce a particular look. If you change font dimensions 2, 3 and 4, for example, you will probably find that you also need to change at least some kerning i.e. the dimensions used to adjust the spacing between pairs of characters because these will otherwise likely look quite odd. Of course, it depends on how subtle the changes you make are, but I wouldn't expect good typographical results if you adjust the dimensions for URW Palladiol to match those of TG Pagella, for example.
For subtle adjustments, microtype provides an easier and safer solution for less effort. For anything more, I would recommend choosing a different font.
1This answer applies specifically to the use of postscript type1 or truetype fonts with 8bit engines i.e. TeX or pdfTeX. A similar story applies to the use of bitmap fonts with such engines, but the details differ. Almost nothing here applies to the use of Unicode fonts with Unicode engines which do not use the files discussed here at all and do not typically require support packages.
2I'm assuming I am not atypical in this respect. I have no positive proof of this. But given that many packages use autoinst precisely because it requires less work than fontinst, for example, it seems prima facie unlikely that package authors typically override foundry/designer decisions in the absence of strong reasons to do so.
3I don't recommend this. I wouldn't do it. But it would be better than forcing font dimensions explicitly in LaTeX documents.

If we are using Unicode fonts then the TeX fontdimen values are saved in an appropriate table. You can use fontforge to inspect the font. Open "Element / Font Info". There are many tabs here, choose "TeX" tab. You can see (for TeXGyrePagella-Regular) following data:
Slant: 0
Space: 250
Stretch: 125
Shrink: 88.333
Xheight: 459
Quad: 1000
Extra space: 83.333

The dimensions are given in 1/1000 em.
